# Why $match returns no data but .find returns some in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongo query like the following:

```
db.membership.find({ "$match" : { "members.sourcedid.id" : "0144401" , "sourcedid.path.store" : "0985" , "sourcedid.path.campus" : "2E3A9B7C-6C8E-433C-85FC-4632FD7C90CD"}})
```

It does not return any result.

But if I run the following it returns result:

```
db.membership.find({ "members.sourcedid.id" : "0144401" , "sourcedid.path.store" : "0985" , "sourcedid.path.campus" : "2E3A9B7C-6C8E-433C-85FC-4632FD7C90CD"})
```

I am not sure why this is happening. Can any one help? I am new to mongodb

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't yield any result because the **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/)** operator is only applicable to the aggregation framework and not in the **[`find()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find)** method.

The above query can be run using the **[`aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate)** method as

```
db.membership.aggregate([
    { 
        "$match" : { 
            "members.sourcedid.id": "0144401", 
            "sourcedid.path.store": "0985", 
            "sourcedid.path.campus": "2E3A9B7C-6C8E-433C-85FC-4632FD7C90CD"
        }
    }
])
```